# ¿Por qué no existen dos verbos diferentes para "dar en alquiler" y "tomar en alquiler"?

Tags: verbos, significado, solicitud-de-término

En español tenemos el verbo *alquilar*, definido así:

> **[alquilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=257cMcn)**
>
> De *alquilé*.
>
> 1. tr. Dar a alguien algo, especialmente una finca urbana, un animal o un mueble, para que use de ello por el tiempo que se determine y
>      mediante el pago de la cantidad convenida.
> 2. tr. Tomar de alguien algo para usarlo por el tiempo y precio convenidos.

Es decir, se usa el mismo verbo tanto desde el punto de vista del arrendador como del arrendatario. Algo completamente diferente a cuando un objeto se compra o se vende, que el verbo cambia según el punto de vista de cada uno de los intervinientes en la transacción.

Esto no es algo reciente, ya que en el *Diccionario de autoridades* tenemos:

> ALQUILAR. v.a. Dar ò tomar en alquilèr alguna cosa, para servirse de ella por cierto précio y tiempo [...]. Usase de este verbo indiferentemente, assi para el dueño que dá en arrendamiento, ò alquilèr, como para el que toma y arrienda el uso y servicio de la cosa. Viene del Arábigo *Quereye*, que vale lo mismo.

¿Por qué esto es así? ¿Por qué usamos el mismo verbo y no dos diferentes como en *comprar/vender*? Pasa incluso con otros verbos sinónimos:

> **[arrendar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3jCFdVS)**
>
> De *renda* 'renta'.
>
> 1. tr. Ceder o adquirir por precio el goce o aprovechamiento temporal de cosas, obras o servicios.

¿No existe o ha existido alguna pareja de verbos para distinguir la acción según el punto de vista del arrendador o arrendatario?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con *[huésped](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlgOxXW)*. No me consta ningún par de verbos que diferencie los dos lados. Cuando lo pienso termino siempre recurriedo a paráfrasis.

Comment: @pablodf76 - ¿Podrías explicar un poco más?

Comment: No lo he pensado antes, pero en ingés es igual. I'm renting an apartment. (I live there and I pay rent) vs. I am renting an apartment (to someone). (I own the apartment and rent it to someone) Hay otros verbos en los dos idiomas que significan dos cosas similares. Muchas veces se combinan con preposiciones diferentes: de o a. O el contexto ayuda.

Comment: *Huésped* refiere a las dos partes de la relación, igual que *alquilar*. Cuando hay que diferenciar, si el contexto no ayuda, hay que decir algo más para dar una pista. (Generalmente el contexto ayuda bastante).

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con **prestar** y creo que con algunos más (mientras en inglés existe _borrow_ y _lend_).

Comment: @DGaleano: En España, prestar solamente se puede utilizar cuando dejas algo a alguien. En la otra dirección se llama tomar prestado.

Comment: @julodnik entonces ¿no entenderían la diferencia entre "Me prestó el carro" y "Le presté el carro" ? ¿Suena muy raro esto en España?

Comment: @DGaleano no suena raro, solo que en ambas frases el sujeto es diferente: "él me prestó" frente a "yo le presté". La acción reflejada es la misma. Si en la primera frase el sujeto fuera "yo", el verbo sería "yo tomé prestado el carro". En cambio, con "alquilar" el verbo no cambia aunque el sujeto se mantenga: "yo alquilo" puede ser "yo tomo en alquiler" o "yo doy en alquiler".

Comment: Sigo sin ver la diferencia. "Yo le alquilé el carro" "El me alquiló el carro". Obvio que si cambio el sujeto se la "dirección de la acción". Pero, si digo **"yo presté/alquilé un carro"** no hay forma de saber si lo di o tomé en préstamo/arriendo.  Mi comentario original simplemente se refiere a que en _prestar_ se comporta igual que _alquilar_ por lo menos en hispanoamérica y según @julodnik no pasa lo mismo en España.

Comment: @DGaleano: Si digo "yo presté un carro" queda claro que el carro era mío y se lo deje a alguien. Si digo "yo alquilé un carro" puede significar que el carro era mío y se lo alquilé a alguien o alguien me lo alquiló a mi.

Comment: @julodnik perfecto. Me queda claro que en España es así. En Colombia "presté un carro" puede ser cualquiera de las dos. (tomé prestado/di en préstamo) Gracias por la información.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La verdad es que hoy en día usamos una terminología bastante apartada del origen del concepto en latín.

Tal como apunta @CarlosAlejo, para el negocio jurídico de compraventa se mantienen los dos aspectos del mismo, la *compra* y la *venta*.

En Derecho Romano se denominaba como *"emptio-venditio"* a la compraventa.  Evidentemente *"emptio"* es comprar y *"venditio"* vender.  Desconozco en qué momento se sustituyó la raíz *"emptum"*, por la de *"comparare"*.

Igualmente, en Derecho Romano, y no olvidemos que es la fuente y origen del Derecho moderno occidental, el contrato de arrendamiento se denominaba ***"locatio-conductio"***.  De este modo, se denominaba ***"loco, locare"*** el acto de ceder en arrenamiento y ***"conducere"*** al de tomarlo.

Si bien no está reconocido por la R.A.E. como verbo, se sigue usando el término **"locar"**, y la R.A.E. sí reconoce el término [**"locación"**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NXeOXqS) como sinónimo del *acto de arrendar*.

Los juristas usamos el verbo "locar" bastante en contratos, demandas, recursos, dictámenes,... yo mismo he usado alguna vez el término ***"locador"*** como sinónimo de arrendador.  Cualquier jurista (abogado, notario, juez, fiscal, registrador, ...) lo va a interpretar correctamente.

El término **"locatario"** como sinónimo de arrendatario sí está reconocido por la [R.A.E.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NXs2Svc)  Extrañamente, no ocurre lo mismo con su contraparte: ***"locador".***

La enciclopedia Espasa sí recoge el término [***"locador"***](http://espasa.planetasaber.com/search/results.asp?txt=locador) como sinónimo de **arrendado**r.  Creo que en hispanoamérica sí se utilizan más estos términos en un ámbito general y no estrictamente jurídico.

**"Las Siete Partidas"** de Alfonso X *El Sabio*.
**Ley XVIII del Título VIII de la Partida V:**

> "Cómo despues que es complido el tiempo del arrendamiento ó del
>   loguero, deber seer tornada la cosa á su dueño.
>
> Complido seyendo el tiempo del arrendamiento ó del loguero, debe seer
>   tornada la cosa asi fuese dada á su señor.  Et si por aventura fuese
>   rebelle el que la toviere, non la queriendo entregar asi como
>   sobredicho es fasta que fuese dado juicio contra él, débela despues
>   tornar doblada a quel que gela arrendó ó gela logó, ó á sus herederos.
>   Otrosi quando algunt menoscabo veniere en aquella cosa por su culpa,
>   débelo pechar."

Comment: Una respuesta muy interesante e instructiva. Es curioso que el latín sí diferenciara las dos acciones, me pregunto qué hizo que al final nos decantáramos por una palabra procedente del árabe a pesar de la confusión que podía provocar. O a lo mejor fue eso, que al poder usar una única palabra para las dos acciones, la gente la usó por simplicidad en vez de tener que aprenderse dos verbos diferentes.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo  Desconozco el momento exacto de dicho cambio, pero sí puedo asegurarte que fue posterior a la redacción de "Las Siete Partidas" del Alfonso X _El Sabio_.  En la partida V, Título VIII, Leyes de la XVIII a la XXIV, que regulaba el arrendamiento se utilizan los términos _"arrendar"_ y **_"logar"_** (añado ejemplo en la respuesta).