# ¿Existen otras palabras "bidireccionales" como el adjetivo "indiferente"?

Tags: ambigüedad

En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23249/how-should-i-understand-que-la-guerra-no-me-sea-indiferente) descubrí que "indiferente" puede tener dos sentidos y referirse a la persona (o cosa) que **causa** indiferencia o a la persona que **siente** indiferencia.

Algo parecido ocurría en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/por-qu%C3%A9-no-existen-dos-verbos-diferentes-para-dar-en-alquiler-y-tomar-en-alq), donde "arrendar" puede usarse para "**dar** en arrendamiento" (desde la perspectiva del locador o arrendador) o para "**tomar** en arrendamiento" (desde la perspectiva del locatario o arrendatario).

Mi pregunta es si podemos pensar en otras palabras (adjetivos, sustantivos, verbos) que puedan tener esa bidireccionalidad, es decir, esas dos perspectivas o sentidos diferentes u opuestos. Obviamente, estas palabras serán firmes candidatas a provocar ambigüedad y deberíamos estar atentos ante su presencia, como hablantes y transmisores de la lengua.

Comment: Cuando tengas tiempo, por favor agrega las contribuciones en letra chiquita, ya sea a la respuesta de James o una nueva.

Answer (score 8):

Los autoantónimos como  :

- [**casero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7oNbEls)

  > 8. m. y f. Dueño de alguna casa, que la alquila a otra persona.
  > 9. m. y f. inquilino (‖ persona que ha tomado una casa en alquiler).
- [**alquilar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=257cMcn)

  > 1. tr. Dar a alguien algo, especialmente una finca urbana, un animal o un mueble, para que use de ello por el tiempo que se   determine y mediante el pago de la cantidad convenida.
  > 2. tr. Tomar de alguien algo para usarlo por el tiempo y precio convenidos.
- [**huésped**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlgOxXW)

  > 1. m. y f. Persona alojada en casa ajena.
  > 2. m. y f. Persona alojada en un establecimiento de hostelería.
  > 3. m. y f. p. us. Mesonero o amo de posada.
  > 4. m. y f. p. us. Persona que hospeda en su casa a otra.
- [**dar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35) clase

  > 14. tr. Impartir una lección, pronunciar una conferencia o charla.
  > 15. tr. Recibir una clase.
- [**oler**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QzRk6op)

  > 1. tr. Percibir los olores.
  > 2. intr. Exhalar y echar de sí fragancia que deleita el sentido del olfato, o hedor que le molesta.
- [**pelón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSpzqC)

  > 1. adj. Que no tiene pelo o tiene muy poco. U. t. c. s.
  > 2. adj. Ec. Que tiene mucho pelo.
- [**enaguas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EuaszT6)

  > 1. f. Prenda **interior** femenina, similar a una falda y que se lleva debajo de esta.U. m. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.
  > 2. f. pl. *Méx*. Prenda **exterior** femenina que cuelga desde la cintura.

y más ejemplos en [Are there any words that have opposite regional meanings?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/324/are-there-any-words-that-have-opposite-regional-meanings/404#404) y en [**Wikilengua**](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enantiosemia).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En realidad, son muy pocas las palabras de la lista que, al menos en mi dialecto, funcionarían como autoantónimos: *sancionar, perla, animal* y no muchas más...

Comment: Yo añadiría el adjetivo "aburrido": causar aburrimiento o sufrir aburrimiento.

Comment: Ésa es muy buena, @FGSUZ. Agregaría "divertido": que divierte a los demás o que se divierte.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Gustavson. La mayoría de las palabras del listado de wikipedia no aplican como autoantónimos. Por ejemplo en Colombia nunca "dar clase" significaría "recibir o asistir a una clase".

Comment: Correcto. Para nosotros sólo sería ambiguo decir "tener clase": el sujeto puede ser profesor o alumno.

Answer (score 3):

Hay calcos de inglés para llamar estes tipos de palabras: *autoantónimos / contrónimos*. Unos ejemplos son:

---

> #### [cantío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7D23kAx)
>
> **al cantío de un gallo**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. *Cuba*. Muy lejos.
> 2. loc. adv. rur. *Cuba*. Muy cerca.

---

> #### [cansado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7AahQRP)
>
> Del part. de *cansar*.
>
> ...
>   3. adj. Que produce cansancio. *Su trabajo es muy cansado.*
>   4. adj. Que manifiesta cansancio. *Rostro cansado.*

---

> #### [pelón, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSpzqC)
>
> 1. adj. Que no tiene pelo o tiene muy poco. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. *Ec.* Que tiene mucho pelo.

---

> #### [jamás](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MKBVDM9)
>
> Del lat. *iam magis* 'ya más'.
>   1. adv. nunca.
>   2. adv. desus. siempre.
>   3. adv. desus. Alguna vez.

---

[Ser/estar aburrido](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/aburrido)

> *Este libro es aburrido. Estoy aburrido de leerlo.*

---

- **alquilar**: dar en alquiler/tomar en alquiler (alogar / alugar)
- **arrendar**: dar en arriendo/tomar en arriendo
- **huésped**: persona que da hospedaje/persona que recibe hospedaje
- **lívido**: amoratado/pálido
- **álgido**: gélido/candente
- **oler**: percibir olor/despedir olor
- **nimio**: grande, abundante/ínfimo, exiguo
- **cruzarse**: encontrarse/desencontrarse
- **enervar**: relajar los nervios/excitar los nervios
- **romper**: interrumpir/dar inicio
- **evento**: acontecimiento imprevisto/acontecimiento organizado
- **picardía** (Arg.): viveza/falta de viveza
- **prestar** (Guat.): dar en préstamo/recibir en préstamo
- **levantar**: construir, armar/desmantelar, desarmar
- **ama**: señora de la casa/criada principal de la casa

---

---

**Fuentes:**

<sup>• [https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/palabras-antónimas-de-sí-mismas.1484286/](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/palabras-ant%C3%B3nimas-de-s%C3%AD-mismas.1484286/)</sup>
<sup>• https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/palabras-que-tienen-significados-opuestos-el-uno-del-otro.377594/</sup>
<sup>• https://www.meneame.net/story/palabra-antonima-de-si-misma</sup>
<sup>• [https://www.translate2travel.com/single-post/2017/05/04/¿Oíste-hablar-de-los-AUTOANTÓNIMOS](https://www.translate2travel.com/single-post/2017/05/04/%C2%BFO%C3%ADste-hablar-de-los-AUTOANT%C3%93NIMOS)</sup>
<sup>• https://www.thoughtco.com/contronyms-in-spanish-3079026</sup>
<sup>• https://es.paperblog.com/controque-3528540/</sup>

Comment: Sobre álgido: https://www.xlsemanal.com/firmas/20190707/de-muy-frio-a-muy-caliente-perez-reverte.html

Answer (score 0):

Volviendo a ver esta pregunta me doy cuenta de que, si bien los ejemplos de autoantónimos están muy bien, no son palabras comparables con "indiferente", en el sentido de que son léxicamente ambiguas, pero no gramaticalmente polivalentes, como sí lo es "indiferente".

Me explico: el predicado "ser indiferente" puede funcionar con dos estructuras o "esqueletos" argumentales, que corresponden a la misma situación subyacente. Una de las estructuras es intransitiva, con un complemento oblicuo opcional:

> *Él es indiferente.*
> *Él es indiferente hacia mí.* (1)

(Caben otras preposiciones además de *hacia*.)

La otra estructura es una frase que formalmente también es intransitiva, pero que toma obligatoriamente un objeto indirecto (OI). Dicho OI corresponde al sujeto de la otra estructura, mientras que el sujeto de esta segunda construcción corresponde al oblicuo de la primera:

> *Yo le soy indiferente.* (2)

En ambos casos estamos hablando de lo mismo; si nominalizamos la frase hablaríamos de "su indiferencia (de él) (hacia mí)".

Aquí el concepto "indiferente" está siendo usado casi exactamente igual que el de "gustar", con la diferencia de que cuando usamos el verbo *gustar* en la primera estructura el complemento es obligatorio:

> *Él gusta de mí.* (1)
>
> *Yo le gusto.* (2)

Es decir, "indiferente" quizá no sea un verdadero autoantónimo: es simplemente la misma palabra, con el mismo significado, usada en dos estructuras sintácticas opuestas, igual que "gustar".

Comment: Te entiendo, Pablo. Por eso mi pregunta apuntaba a palabras que bauticé como "bidireccionales", en el sentido de que se alternan sujeto y objeto. "Indiferente" también puede serlo. Por ejemplo: *¿Qué sos para ella? / Soy indiferente // ¿Cómo sos con ella? / Soy indiferente.*